# Deducing Laguerre Polynomials

Tags: special-functions

Studying for a final and came accross this problem in the textbook. Considering I have no idea how to even start im a bit scared :). Any explanation would be greatly appreciated.

**problem:** If f(x)is a polynomial of degree m, show that f(x) may be expressed in the form $$f(x)=\sum_{r=0}^m c_rL_r(x)$$
with $c_r=\int_{0}^\infty e^{-x}L_r(x)f(x)dx$.

Deduce that $\int_{0}^\infty e^{-x}x^kL_n(t)dt=0$ if $k<n$

and $\int_{0}^\infty e^{-x}x^kL_n(t)dt=0$ if $k=n$

Comment: Have you tried working from the definitions? Laguerre Polynomials have some nice well-known properties. Perhaps it helps  to see that the integrand can be written as a sum of terms of the form $\int_{0}^{\infty}\alpha_n e^{-x}x^n$. Integrating by parts...

Comment: I think my confusion right now is is this a 3 part problem? If so I don't understand what i am being asked to do on the f(x) with $c_r$ part.

Comment: Ah, I'd say this is a *two part problem* since the deductions arise naturally by arriving at the first part (the part with $c_r$'s). I'm assuming, however, that you meant $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}x^k L_{n}(x)\,dx=0$ if $k<n$ and, moreover, that you meant $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}x^n L_n (x)\,dx\ne 0$. Use the generating function of the $L_n$'s if you know it to avoid a hassle with sums.